# Does Java Operator "==" really compare two objects based on memory reference?

Tags: java, operators

As the java-doc tells Java Operator `==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object). so "==" operator will return true only if two object reference it is comparing represent exactly same object otherwise `"=="` will return false.

But while running a piece of code all i found is that this statement doesn't satisfy the Output of the code.
Here's the code:

```
public class Test2 {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         String s="Sachin";  
         String t="Sachin";
         System.out.println(s==t); 
    }
}
```

And Surprisingly i found a output `"true"`.
Please Help me understand why it is so?

Here's a Screenshot to my program output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ0PW.jpg

Comment: I don't understand, why you ask for the `==` operator, if your provided code does not use that in all, but uses the `equals` operator.

Comment: `s` and `t` refer to the same object due to the interning of the strings; i.e. the compiler is being clever. Lots of duplicates on this.

Comment: [REMOVED] - After running your code: The result is `false`, your question is not reproducable.

Comment: @Bathsheba 
what do you mean by  interning of the strings?

Comment: Well, **sometimes** is `true` and sometimes is `false`...

Comment: Yeah please just go ahead and edit the question. Now it doesn't even print true.

Comment: @Prometheus! Take a look at `String.intern()` method and what it does. This is exaclty what happend to your updated question.

Comment: @MuratK. Here's a Screen Shot of  my output
https://ibb.co/jFVFm6

Comment: @zlakad It should always be true. From [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28): *Compile-time constant expressions of type String are always "interned"*

Comment: @Prometheus Yes, you changed your question like 5 times

Comment: @Michael, that is correct, but *only* if the Strings are *Compile-time constants* like you said. I've tried to encourage using `equals` in every case... ;)

Comment: @zlakad And both strings here are compile time constants. Your comment makes it sound like the result of `s == t` in this case is non-deterministic, and that's not true.

Comment: @Michael I agree, but the question was edited several times - so... It's too late to delete the comment right now. No bad feelings, friend.

Comment: @Michael, I know I can delete the comment, but since we had this conversation it wouldn't be nice (that is the context of "I'ts too late to delete...")

Answer (score 4):

You assuption is that

> ```
>      String s="Sachin";  
>      String t="Sachin";
> ```

creates *two* string objects, but this is not true.

Java optimises the usage of string so that is puts *literal strings* in the *string pool* so that it assinges an already created string object from that pool if the compiler finds the same string a second time. This is called *string interning*.

You better try this:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         String s="Sachin";  
         String t=new String(s);
         System.out.println(s==t); 
    }
}
```

Comment: "if the compiler finds the same string a second time" even if the literal occurs just once, it will use the object from the constant pool.

Comment: @AndyTurner thought I wrote just that with other words, didn't I?

Comment: "if the compiler finds the same string a second time" implies that it doesn't do it the first time, but does the second.

Comment: @AndyTurner but the sentence before, I thought...